# how to extract camera related information from image

Tags: image, camera, metadata, exif

How can I extract camera related information (eg. camera model, date taken etc) from an image stored in the database? For example, I resized an image and uploaded it and saved its path in database. I want to display basic camera information while displaying the image, therefore I want to extract the information. Thanks.

Comment: What language? Or do you want to do this with an application such as Photoshop?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add.. I'm doing in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to read the EXIF data. For PHP, [use exif_read_data](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php). Sample:

```
<?php
$exif = exif_read_data('img.jpg');
$model = $exif['Model'];
$iso = $exif['ISOSpeedRatings'];
$taken = $exif['DateTime'];
```

Comment: Thanks.. I'm using php and this is what i'm looking for.. however, there seems to be a problem. it only reads data if the image is in original form. However I resize images before uploading and it does not seem to get data from resized images. Is there anyway to get data from resized images?

Comment: What application do you use to resize your image? Some applications erase or overwrite the exif data.

Answer (score 1):

What is the image type?  What language are you using?

Assuming, for example, you're talking about JPG images then what you're probably trying to do is read the EXIF data from the file.  If you're using, for example, Java then there are various libraries [such as this one](http://www.drewnoakes.com/drewnoakes.com/code/exif/) to help you.

Google will uncover many, many more depending on your language/environment.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to obtain is the EXIF data.

Take a look here for some suggestions about libraries/etc...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format#Program_support

PHP has an EXIF library: http://php.net/manual/en/book.exif.php