# Figure out with which device was a picture taken from - Is it possible?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

This might seem a bit odd to ask, but I couldn't get an answer through Google - maybe because I wasn't using the correct keywords, but is there a way **to find out** (either through javascript, jQuery, PHP or any other way) **from what device a picture was taken** (For example: via webcam or phone or camera etc)?

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, but please excuse if I'm at the wrong place.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What information are you starting with? Just the photo file?

Comment: I'm using flash to capture a screenshot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [exif_read_data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php)

```
$exif = exif_read_data('a.jpg');
var_dump($exif);
```

*Please note that the Device information is not always available*

Comment: After going through the link, I can't seem to find where the hardware source is mentioned in the returned array

Comment: Yep. Got it. Thanks. Will accept the answer in 2 mins as it is not allowing me to at the moment

Answer (score 1):

> You want to read the EXIF data. For PHP, use [exif_read_data](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php).
>   Sample:
>
> ```
> <?php
>    $exif = exif_read_data('a.jpg');
>    $model = $exif['Model'];
>    $iso = $exif['ISOSpeedRatings'];
>    $taken = $exif['DateTime'];
> ?>
> ```

The above is from the following [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485119/how-to-extract-camera-related-information-from-image) by [Alexn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41596/alexn)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php

But that will only work for JPEG or TIFF according to the documentation.

PS: Javascript or JQuery? JQuery *is* Javascript (sort of).

Comment: Yes,but jQuery reduces a lot of lines when compared to javascript